# Changing urls while scrolling without hash

Tags: jquery-waypoints

using waypoints.js it's possible to change the url dynamically while scrolling but using a hash.

Is it possible to change it without a hash, so any waypoint can be reached with its own url?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think that you'll need some kind of related identity / value between the waypoint element and the url.